# Understanding what clang is doing in assembly, decrementing for a loop that is incrementing

Tags: c++, assembly, increment, compiler-optimization, clang++

Consider the following code, in C++:

```
#include <cstdlib>

std::size_t count(std::size_t n)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        asm volatile("": : :"memory");
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return count(argc > 1 ? std::atoll(argv[1]) : 1);
}
```

It is just a loop that is incrementing its value, and returns it at the end. The `asm volatile` prevents the loop from being optimized away. We compile it under `g++ 8.1` and `clang++ 5.0` with the arguments `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -g -O3`.

Now, if we look at what [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/pwfCSK) is producing, we have, for `g++`:

```
count(unsigned long):
  mov rax, rdi
  test rdi, rdi
  je .L2
  xor edx, edx
.L3:
  add rdx, 1
  cmp rax, rdx
  jne .L3
.L2:
  ret
main:
  mov eax, 1
  xor edx, edx
  cmp edi, 1
  jg .L25
.L21:
  add rdx, 1
  cmp rdx, rax
  jb .L21
  mov eax, edx
  ret
.L25:
  push rcx
  mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
  mov edx, 10
  xor esi, esi
  call strtoll
  mov rdx, rax
  test rax, rax
  je .L11
  xor edx, edx
.L12:
  add rdx, 1
  cmp rdx, rax
  jb .L12
.L11:
  mov eax, edx
  pop rdx
  ret
```

and for clang++:

```
count(unsigned long): # @count(unsigned long)
  test rdi, rdi
  je .LBB0_1
  mov rax, rdi
.LBB0_3: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  dec rax
  jne .LBB0_3
  mov rax, rdi
  ret
.LBB0_1:
  xor edi, edi
  mov rax, rdi
  ret
main: # @main
  push rbx
  cmp edi, 2
  jl .LBB1_1
  mov rdi, qword ptr [rsi + 8]
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor esi, esi
  mov edx, 10
  call strtoll
  test rax, rax
  jne .LBB1_3
  mov eax, ebx
  pop rbx
  ret
.LBB1_1:
  mov eax, 1
.LBB1_3:
  mov rcx, rax
.LBB1_4: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  dec rcx
  jne .LBB1_4
  mov rbx, rax
  mov eax, ebx
  pop rbx
  ret
```

Understanding the code generated by g++, is not that complicated, the loop being:

```
.L3:
  add rdx, 1
  cmp rax, rdx
  jne .L3
```

every iteration increments `rdx`, and compares it to `rax` that stores the size of the loop.

Now, I have no idea of what clang++ is doing. Apparently it uses `dec`, which is weird to me, and I don't even understand where the actual loop is. My question is the following: what is clang doing?

(I am looking for comments about the clang assembly code to describe what is done at each step and how it actually works).

Comment: counting from 0 -> n or n -> 0. comparing to 0 might be faster.

Comment: it is decrementing `n` rather than incrementing `i`. It is not maintaining an `i` value at all since you never do anything with it. IT kept a copy of n as the return value

Comment: @pm100 But at the function returns `i`... and `i` should be equal to `n`. If `n` is decremented then what is returned by the function? (where is the value that actually needs to be returned?)

Comment: It keeps the input parameter in rdi and moves it to rax just before ret. Rax contains the return value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect of the function is to return `n`, either by counting up to `n` and returning the result, or by simply returning the passed-in value of `n`. The clang code does the latter. The counting loop is here:

```
   mov rax, rdi
.LBB0_3: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  dec rax
  jne .LBB0_3
  mov rax, rdi
  ret
```

It begins by copying the value of `n` into `rax`. It decrements the value in `rax`, and if the result is not 0, it jumps back to `.LBB0_3`. If the value **is** 0 it falls through to the next instruction, which copies the original value of `n` into `rax` and returns.

There is no `i` stored, but the code does the loop the prescribed number of times, and returns the value that `i` would have had, namely, `n`.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thanks!